# How to implement substraction expression in my ANTLR4 Java extended Listener class?

Tags: java, antlr4

I have a task to remake my ANTLR4 Java project, which was using visitor, into the same project, which is using listener. 
I am having trouble with understanding how listener works.

My visitor substract method looked like this:

```
// expression '-' expression                #subtractExpression
@Override
public QuickMathsValue visitSubtractExpression(SubtractExpressionContext ctx) {
    QuickMathsValue lhs = this.visit(ctx.expression(0));
    QuickMathsValue rhs = this.visit(ctx.expression(1));
    if (lhs.isNumber() && rhs.isNumber()) {
        return new QuickMathsValue(lhs.asDouble() - rhs.asDouble());
    }
    throw new EvalException(ctx);
}
```

How to make the same thing, but with Listener? If anybody has any examples, it would be a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your listener you could add a stack on which you push your values. When exiting a rule, you pop the needed values from the stack and then push them back on again (added or multiplied or other).

A quick demo:

### Expression.g4

```antlr
grammar Expression;

expression
 : expression op=( MUL | DIV ) expression #expressionMul
 | expression op=( ADD | MIN ) expression #expressionAdd
 | '(' expression ')'                     #expressionNested
 | NUMBER                                 #expressionNumber
 ;

MUL    : '*';
DIV    : '/';
ADD    : '+';
MIN    : '-';
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )?;
SPACE  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

### Main.java

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String expression = "(1 + 2) * 14";
    ExpressionLexer lexer = new ExpressionLexer(CharStreams.fromString(expression));
    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    EvalListener evaluator = new EvalListener();
    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(evaluator, parser.expression());

    System.out.printf("%s = %s\n", expression, evaluator.stack.pop());
  }

  static class EvalListener extends ExpressionBaseListener {

    final Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<>();

    @Override
    public void exitExpressionAdd(ExpressionParser.ExpressionAddContext ctx) {
      Double rhs = stack.pop();
      Double lhs = stack.pop();
      this.stack.push(ctx.op.getType() == ExpressionLexer.ADD ? (lhs + rhs) : (lhs - rhs));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitExpressionMul(ExpressionParser.ExpressionMulContext ctx) {
      Double rhs = stack.pop();
      Double lhs = stack.pop();
      this.stack.push(ctx.op.getType() == ExpressionLexer.MUL ? (lhs * rhs) : (lhs / rhs));
    }

    @Override
    public void enterExpressionNumber(ExpressionParser.ExpressionNumberContext ctx) {
      this.stack.push(Double.valueOf(ctx.getText()));
    }
  }
}
```

Running the `Main` class will result in the following output:

```
(1 + 2) * 14 = 42.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been a great help!